# Memory leak in MIDI

Tags: java

I tried using this to display MIDI code on the console, found that memory keep going up by 4Kb by 4Kb or more even when there is no midi event input. Wonder what caused memory leak?

http://www.jsresources.org/examples/MidiInDump.html

Which profiler help to identify which function caused the leak?

Would appreciate if you can help testing the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory leak in MIDI Receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358667/memory-leak-in-midi-receiver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JDK comes with [jvisualvm](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).

See also [The Best Kept Secret in the JDK: VisualVM](http://java.dzone.com/articles/best-kept-secret-jdk-visualvm).

Comment: Had tried this before, it seem the issue doesn't lie in any part of my code except Java Sound API.

Comment: @user: it's **highly** unlikely that the problem lies in the Java library and not elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I start anther question which I figure the two lines of code might have memory leak. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395153/memory-leak-in-dumpreceiver